# MassTransit : why don't I get a queue created when publishing a message?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have seen the [examples of MassTransit](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-GettingStarted), but the fact that both the publisher and the consumer are in the same application in them, confuses me. I would expect the configuration for publisher and consumer to be completely separate.

I have a (.NET Framework) program which I want to only publish messages/events with this code:

```
            _bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.Host(new Uri(rabbitmqConfig.Host), h => {
                    h.Username(rabbitmqConfig.Username);
                    h.Password(rabbitmqConfig.Password);
                });

                // I am not even sure if the following are relevant for a publisher...
                sbc.UseRetry(retryConfig);

                if (concurrentMessageLimit.HasValue)
                    sbc.UseConcurrencyLimit(concurrentMessageLimit.Value);

                if(useDelayedMessageScheduler)
                    sbc.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

                if (batchConfig != null)
                    sbc.UseRateLimit(batchConfig.BatchSize, batchConfig.Delay);
            });

            await _bus.StartAsync();
            await _bus.Publish(new MyEvent(data));
```

Is this publisher code correct?

This creates an exchange in RabbitMQ (and I don't like the name it uses much), but it doesn't create a queue and the published messages seems lost.

Then I have another (.NET6) application that consumes messages, with this code:

```
builder.Services
    .AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddConsumer<MyEventConsumer>();

        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host("rabbitmq://localhost", conf => {
                conf.Username("guest");
                conf.Password("guest");
            });
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });
```

When this runs, it doesn't create a queue either. Nor does the code handle any messages. What is going on? How can I make those two apps work together?

I have used RabbitMQ alone in the past, and it was manageable. With MassTransit, I don't seem to be able to figure out how the configuration works...

Comment: Review, the logs, all the logs. IF you don't see logs, get logs working.